# How to record numeric field with masking in Selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium ide (Firefox) to record a form having number field. They have applied Masking in the field. Selenium is not recording this field. Can someone help?

Code in firebug looks like this

```
input id="new" type="text" data-bind="value: Record, jqInputMask: { alias: 'numeric',rightAlign: false }" size="4"
```

Comment: storeValue isn't returning anything? You might have to figure out the javascript call to unmask the field.

Comment: Guess, but looks like there is a .val() function you could possibly run?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `sendKeys` command to simulate user input on a masked field

Comment: possibly with a click before?